# arXiv identifier in square brackets

Tags: biblatex, arxiv

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=phys,articletitle=true,biblabel=brackets,%
chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false,eprint=true,backend=biber,%
natbib=true,maxbibnames=10,giveninits=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textit{#1\isdot}}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\urlstyle{same}
\addbibresource{References.bib}


\begin{document}


This is a test.


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My `References.bib` file is instead

```
@article{rs11999,
   Archiveprefix = {arXiv},
   Author = {Randall, Lisa and Sundrum, Raman},
   Doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.83.3370},
   Eprint = {hep-ph/9905221},
   Journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
   Pages = {3370},
   Title = {{A Large Mass Hierarchy from a Small Extra Dimension}},
   Volume = {83},
   Year = {1999},
   Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.83.3370}}
```

In the output the bibliography looks like

[image]

I would like to remove the last comma and surround the arXiv identifier with square brackets. Can anybody help me here? Thanks.

EDIT
Adding the following article to the `References.bib` file presents both the problems I mentioned in the comments:

```
@article{bhj2017,
   Archiveprefix = {arXiv},
   Author = {Bunk, Don and Hubisz, Jay and Jain, Bithika},
   Eprint = {1705.00001},
   Primaryclass = {hep-ph},
   Title = {{A Perturbative RS I Cosmological Phase Transition}}}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen to the `primaryclass`? Should it disappear? Be in no brackets, or square brackets within square brackets?

Comment: @moewe Square brackets within square brackets if possible.

Comment: I have changed my code to give square brackets within square brackets.

Comment: The problem with `bhj2017` is that `@article` is not the appropriate entry type. `@article` is only appropriate if the paper was actually published in a journal, i.e. only if the `journal` field is non-empty. in this case you should use `@online` instead. Cf. `baez/online` and `baez/article` in `biblatex-examples.bib`.

Comment: @moewe With the `@online` entry type I get `[20] D. Bunk, J. Hubisz, B. Jain, A Perturbative RS I Cosmological Phase Transition, [arXiv:1705.00001 [hep-ph]]`. The only difference is that the title is in italic. Shouldn't there be no comma between the title and the arXiv identifier?

Comment: Ah yes, that is because `@online` is special when it comes to `eprint`s. Have a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the eprint field in brackets only for arXiv you need

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=phys, articletitle=true, biblabel=brackets,%
  chaptertitle=false, pageranges=false, eprint=true, backend=biber,%
  natbib=true, maxbibnames=10, giveninits=true, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\mkbibitalic{#1\isdot}}% I'd even use \mkbibemph
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\urlstyle{same}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibfixedbrackets}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \bibleftbracket#1\bibrightbracket
  \endgroup}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{arxiv}} or test {\iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{arXiv}}}
    {\setunit{\addspace}\newblock}
    {\newunit\newblock}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\newunit\newblock
   \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
     {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
     {}}
  {\ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{arxiv}} or test {\iffieldequalstr{eprinttype}{arXiv}}}
     {\setunit{\addspace}\newblock}
     {\newunit\newblock}%
   \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
     {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
     {}}
  {}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:arxiv}{%
  \mkbibbrackets{%
    \ifhyperref
      {\href{http://arxiv.org/\abx@arxivpath/#1}{%
          arXiv\addcolon
          \nolinkurl{#1}%
          \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
       {}
       {\addspace\UrlFont{\mkbibfixedbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}
      {arXiv\addcolon
        \nolinkurl{#1}%
        \iffieldundef{eprintclass}
          {}
          {\addspace\UrlFont{\mkbibfixedbrackets{\thefield{eprintclass}}}}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{itzhaki,baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> N. Itzhaki, *Some remarks on ’t Hooft’s S-matrix for black holes*, version 1, (Mar. 11, 1996) [arXiv:hep-th/9603067].
>
> J. C. Baez, A. D. Lauda, “Higher-dimensional algebra V: 2-groups”, version 3, *Theory and Applications of Categories* **12**, 423 (2004) [arXiv:math/0307200v3].

---

If you want all `eprint`s in brackets, you'd only need

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{eprint}{%
  \iffieldundef{eprint}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
       \iffieldundef{eprinttype}
         {\printfield{eprint}}
         {\printfield[eprint:\strfield{eprinttype}]{eprint}}}}}
```

But there is currently a small bug in `biblatex`  and `biblatex-phys` that causes an unwanted space here. Both issues have been addressed ([plk/biblatex@`36a0833`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/36a0833bc010d29c68f36d26acb4cc4ac0da1cc8) and [josephwright/biblatex-phys@`e8a8410`](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-phys/commit/e8a84107bcf9c723ba7c45bb2324921b0277cc94)), the fixes will be included in the upcoming versions of the two packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go with your second solution. However, with the new arXiv identifier scheme the eprintclass is surrounded by parenthesis instead of brackets. Moreover, for articles in which I specify only authors and title (since they have not been published in a journal) there is still a comma between the title and the arXiv identifier.

Comment: @gabo_18 Can you modify your MWE to include examples of the two problems? I will have a look at them then.